# Java regex splitting, but only removing one whitespace

Tags: java, regex, format

I have this code:

```
String[] parts = sentence.split("\\s");
```

and a sentence like: `"this is a whitespace   and I want to split it"` (note there are 3 whitespaces after "whitespace")

I want to split it in a way, where only the last whitespace will be removed, keeping the original message intact. The output should be

`"[this], [is], [a], [whitespace  ], [and], [I], [want], [to], [split], [it]"`
(two whitespaces after the word "whitespace")

Can I do this with regex and if not, is there even a way?

I removed the `+` from `\\s+` to only remove one whitespace

Comment: What should happen in situation when after last word there are also spaces like `"foo  bar  "` (there are two spaces after each word). What should be result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
String[] parts = sentence.split("\\s(?=\\S)");
```

That will split with a whitespace char that is immediately followed with a non-whitespace char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/38pHij/1). *Details*:

- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires a non-whitespace char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

To make it fully Unicode-aware in Java, add the `(?U)` (`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option equivalent) embedded flag option: `.split("(?U)\\s(?=\\S)")`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a real life saver! :)